# Prevent access of a public action in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have build a MVC 5 application. Now is time to publish it to production.
The infrastructure consist of two servers: one that can be accessed on internet and the other that is accessed only in intranet.
Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 and uses IIS 8.5 to host the application.

The application consist of backend and frontend. Backend's functionality are accessible only with login.

The problem that I want to solve is: How can I prevent login to the application from Internet and allow it only in intranet?

I think that might be some configuration on web.config to prevent opening of login page.

I have read a lot articles, but all the results are to prevent pages of unauthorized users. In my case login controller has `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and it can be accessed without authorization.

If it can be done with a simple configuration in web.config I am going to add a key in web.config to keep track where it is the server on internet or the server on intranet like:

```
//for server accessible on intranet
<add key="serverType" value="PUBLIC"/>

// or

//for server accessible on intranet
<add key="serverType" value="Private"/>
```

And in the corresponding controller for login I will check for the value and if it is `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverType"] == "PUBLIC"` I will redirect it to site public home page.

Does this solution have any security issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would change the config with transforms or Parameterization (I prefer this one) to use the appropriate authentication type.  For example, Anonymous for public and Windows/Forms Auth for private.  You would have a transform/parameterization for each server type.

The following posts provide more specifics around ASP.NET security.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfs7yc7.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx